# replication menu not found in phpmyadmin server of cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to make database synchronization using phpmyadmin with the help of replication,but i am not getting replication button in phpmyadmin of Cpanel. What i need to do to get that replication button in cpanel ?

Comment: see the documentation: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq9-1 This option is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your phpMyAdmin and cPanel are the same as mine and assuming you're trying to COPY a database and assuming your other database is not yet set up, you need to do the following:

1. Log into cPanel
2. Go to databases and click 'MySQL Databases'
3. Create a new database.
4. Create a new user.
5. Add user to database.
6. Go Back to the main cPanel area and head for phpMyAdmin.
7. Log into phpMyAdmin and click your database to open the structure.
8. Click the 'operations' tab at the top.
9. Look for 'copy database to:'
10. Click 'structure and data'
11. Type your new db name into the text box.
12. Press 'Go'.

If you already have your database set up, skip to step 7.

If the database where you're dumping the data is not empty, I would advise truncating it first to prevent any issues.